# dotCover do not cover Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper, dotcover

I have created a simple class BankAccount

```
public class BankAccount {
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount) {
        this.Balance -= amount;
    }

    public void Deposit(decimal amount) {
        this.Balance += amount;
    }

    public void WithdrawOrDeposit(decimal amount) {
        if (amount < 0) {
            this.Withdraw(Math.Abs(amount));
        } else {
            this.Deposit(amount);
        }
    }
}
```

For this class I have implemented some Tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BankAccountTests {
    private BankAccount account;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp() {
        this.account = new BankAccount {Balance = 100};
    }

    [Test]
    public void WithdrawTest() {
        this.account.Withdraw(50);
        Assert.That(this.account.Balance, Is.EqualTo(50));
    }

    [Test]
    public void WithdrawOrDepositTest() {
        this.account.WithdrawOrDeposit(50);
        Assert.That(this.account.Balance, Is.EqualTo(150));
    }
}
```

When I execute now dotCover, it is showing me 0% Testcoverage for the Method  `BankAccount.WithdrawOrDeposite()` but I dont know why. There is a Test, which does test one case of the method.

[image: dotCover]

What am I doing wrong? The goal is to show, that 50% of `BankAccount.WithdrawOrDeposite()` would be covered by a test. Is this possible?

Comment: Just a tip that using values of 100 and 50 leaves your test vulnerable to passing by coincidence. Consider using a value `x` where `100-x!=x`.

Comment: Another tip that `this.Withdraw(Math.Abs(amount));` would be more efficient as `this.Withdraw(-amount);` since you already know it is negative.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like only WithdrawTest was executed with coverage analysis. Could you please try to execute "Cover Current Session" action (see the dropdown menu under the "Run Current Session" button)?